# How to unbind existing click event on a button and replace it with new event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-frontend

Basically what I am trying to do is :

I cloned a button and hide the existing button with cloned one. I want to bind a new function on the cloned button and want to remove previous events.

I have tried removeEventListener() but didn't work.

I shared a piece of code to get a better understanding.

```
let formSelector = document.querySelectorAll('form[action="/cart/add"]');
formSelector.forEach(function(e) {
e.setAttribute("data-plusbooster-offer", true);
let addToCart__button = e.querySelectorAll('[name="add"]') 
                      || e.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"]') 
                      || e.querySelectorAll(__addToCart__class__static);


addToCart__button.forEach(function(response) {
    let cloneBtn = response.cloneNode(true);
    cloneBtn.classList.add(["plusbooster__btn"],["__addUpsell"]);

    cloneBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "removeThat(this)");

    response.parentNode.insertBefore(cloneBtn, response);
    response.classList.add("plusbooster__hidden");
    response.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute` to install event listeners, and don't put code in string literals.

Comment: `removeEventListener` will only work in combination with `addEventListener`.

Comment: So what do you suggest to use instead of `setAttribute` ?? 
Should I use `addEventListener` to install event listeners?

Comment: Yes. Either that, or the simpler `.onclick` property which you can simply overwrite to remove a listener.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` providing a reference to the **same event handler function**

> You can remove an Event Listener **only if you have a reference to the function used as a handler when the event listener was added**. If an annonymous function is used, the listener will not be removable.

You can see in the following example, the appropiate way to attach and remove event listeners :

```js
// select element
let myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');

// Handler 1
function myHandler_1(e){
    alert('Handler 1')
}

// Handler 2
function myHandler_2(e){
    alert('Handler 2')
}

// add a click event listener using myHandler_1()
myElement.addEventListener('click',myHandler_1)
// remove the previous assigned event handler
myElement.removeEventListener('click',myHandler_1)

// add another click event listener using myHandler_2()
myElement.addEventListener('click',myHandler_2)

// test : on click event you will see how the first 
// listener has been removed, and instead only the 
// second one is triggered
```

```html
<div id="myElement">click me</div>
```

> You can find **more details** and considerations in [mozilla developer pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Hello @colxi, 
Thanks for your response to this question... 

I am making a dynamic script for multiple websites to use, So I am not sure which function will be binded with that button... but I want to remove all the functions running/attached on that click event. 

Do you have any suggestions on how I can make it more dynamic?

Comment: Take a look at the **Element.prototype.getEventListeners** library. It will return an Object containing **all the binded events** of an element. You can find it here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/geteventlisteners